# TeXShop console (not log) contains entire LuaLaTeX file

Tags: luatex, unicode, accents, texshop, lua

I tried the example of "von" in the post

[Is direct utf8 input of combining diacritics in math mode possible with lualatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77596/is-direct-utf8-input-of-combining-diacritics-in-math-mode-possible-with-lualatex)

regarding the use of a Lua script to allow TeX commands for combining characters (normally preceding the modified character) to appear as Unicode (normally following the modified character), in math as it already works in text.

It worked fine, but in TeXShop the Console window showed also the complete content of the "document" part of the `.tex` file.  However, the same did not appear in the log file.

I extended the `.tex` file to define other accents, & made them work as suggested in text & math modes.  Then I added packages, and a bibliography.

Still worked well, but then the contents of the `.sty` & `.bbl` files also appeared in the Console (but not log).

This makes the Console contents rather long, so how do I stop it?  I haven't tested other TeX front ends, & I don't know squat about Lua scripting, so I don't know whether to blame the script, LuaTeX itself, or TeXShop.  (von's example is rather minimal, so I don't think I need to reduce it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the output you are seeing is the line

```lua
print(table.concat(t))
```

in the function `dobuffer`.  It can safely be removed, and the console output will disappear.

Comment: Right you are. I added that for debugging purposes when I wrote the lua script, and I should probably have removed the print statement when posting the script. I've edited the original now, removing the print statement as suggested here.